# How to convert little endian PCM audio samples to big endian

Tags: c++, audio, endianness, rtp

I need to fill a datagram buffer with network byte ordered audio samples per the apt-x RTP layout per [RFC 7310 section 5.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7310#section-5.5):

This is how the layout of audio samples sits in my application memory:

- 24 bit packed little endian samples.

My application buffer in this case is also compacted (audio byte layout - little endian as I am on a PC): note I reversed the **LSB** & **MSB** order below comparing it to the layout shown at the end of section 5.5 in the RFC as the RFC shows big endian samples) - ignore the last byte here, as in compacted form, this blank byte would be the LSB for next audio sample etc.)

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |      LSB      |       MB      |      MSB      |               |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   little endian memory layout for 24 bit signed pcm sample.
```

I need to **memcpy** my application buffer to the destination datagram buffer (starting at offset 12, as I already have a correctly formatted big endian RTP header already at the start of the buffer).

Should I ***std::reverse*** my application buffer and then call memcpy or do I need some special endian library call that understandas the layout of the 24 bit signed samples? I belive the nomenclature of these samples is spcm24-le (signed pcm 24 bit little endian).

Imagine the audio samples as an array ***std::uint32_t[number of samples]*** of audio in intel memory (once they arrive from the microphone).  In order to convert these to spcm24-le, I can simply shift each of these samples **right** by 8 bits to convert each sample to a signed pcm24 (still little endian) - but I don't know how to insert this into the target datagram buffer nicely packed and organized per the RFC.

A simple example in c++ would be great - perhaps using `std::endian` or `std::reverse` of `std::byteswap` ??

```
   For the example format, the diagram below shows how coded samples
   from each channel are packed into a sample block and how sample
   blocks 1, 2, and 48 are subsequently packed into the RTP packet.

      C:
      Channel index: Left (l) = 1, left center (lc) = 2,
      center (c) = 3, right (r) = 4, right center (rc) = 5,
      and surround (S) = 6.

      T:
      Sample Block time index: The first sample block is 1; the final
      sample is 48.

      S(C)(T):
      The Tth sample from channel C.

Lindsay & Foerster           Standards Track                    [Page 8]
RFC 7310                    apt-X RTP Format                   July 2014

    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    S(1)(1)                    |    S(2)(1)    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    S(2)(1)    |            S(3)(1)            |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |    S(3)(1)    |                   S(4)(1)                     |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    S(5)(1)                    |    S(6)(1)    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    S(6)(1)    |            S(1)(2)            |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |    S(2)(2)    |                   S(3)(2)                     |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    S(4)(2)                    |    S(5)(2)    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    S(5)(2)    |            S(6)(2)            |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |    S(6)(2)    |                   S(1)(3)                     |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |            S(6)(47)           |            S(1)(48)           |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |    S(1)(48)   |                   S(2)(48)                    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    S(3)(48)                   |    S(4)(48)   |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                   S(4)(48)    |           S(5)(48)            |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |    S(5)(48)   |                   S(6)(48)                    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

   For the example format, the diagram below indicates the order that
   coded bytes are packed into the packet payload in terms of sample
   byte significance.  The following abbreviations are used.

      MSB:
      Most Significant Byte of a 24-bit coded sample

      MB:
      Middle Byte of a 24-bit coded sample

      LSB:
      Least Significant Byte of a 24-bit coded sample

Lindsay & Foerster           Standards Track                    [Page 9]
RFC 7310                    apt-X RTP Format                   July 2014

    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |      MSB      |       MB      |      LSB      |               |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Comment: How do you store the data? Show some minimal sample please.

Comment: And you're presenting three questions in one which makes it really big investment for anyone who decides to write an answer for you.

Comment: Hmmm I guess I could remove the last 2 (they might be simpler to handle myself) let me edit the question, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Red.Wave look at "This is how the layout of audio samples sits in my application memory:"  - I just edited the question to remove 2 of the easier questions.  The memory is laid out in ram in compacted 3 byte little endian format - so the if you think of my applicatino buffer as a uint8_t buff [datagram size], buff[0] would contain my audio sample 0 LSB, buff[1] would contain my audio sample 0 MB, & buff[2] would contain my audio sample 0 MSB,  .. buff[3] would contain my audio sample 1 LSB, .... etc.

Comment: This `buff` is not stated inside the question. Process requirements are also missing; is this a realtime solution? Quality degradation, sample loss tolerance? GPU, CPU or SIMD? These and a lot more questions are involved with the **audio** part of the question. If a reordering of bytes in memory is all needed, then the rest of the post is noise. That's why you need to provide a minimal skeleton for the code, and ask for some meat.

Comment: @Red.Wave the real time nature is irrelevant - as far as quality goes there should be no quality loss - its just a question on how to re-layout byte aligned audio data as I described in my previous comment (which describes 3 byte audio samples ordered in little endian audio (LSB, MB, MSB)(LSB, MB, MSB)(LSB, MB, MSB)... (without a 4th padding byte to align each sample on a 32 bit boundary boundary)  and order the destination byte bufffer as (MSB, MB, LSB)(MSB, MB, LSB)(MSB, MB, LSB).... (the initial address in both the source and target buffers is 32 bit aligned. - I just need portable C++code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use C++23 for readability and enhanced safety. The logic can then be downgraded for older standards:

```
#include <bit>
#include <ranges>
void in_place_reorder(std::span<std::byte> buffer){ 
    namespace rv = std::views;
    if (std::endian::native == std::endian::big)
        for(auto && [first, _ , last]: buffer | rv::adjacent<3> | rv::stride(3))
            std::swap(first,last);
};

std::vector<std::byte> in_vec{/*...*/};
std::array<std::byte, N> in_arr{/*...*/};
in_place_reorder(in_vec);
in_place_reorder(in_arr);
```

If the source is supposed to stay intact I would just create an adapter:

```
namespace rv = std::views;
auto constexpr reorder = rv::chunk(3) | rv::transform(rv::reverse) | join;

std::vector<std::byte> input{/*...*/};
auto output = input | reorder | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();

std::vector<std::byte> output2(size(input));
std::ranges::copy(input | reorder, begin(output2);
```

If C++23 is not available equivalent can be done with **ranges-v3** open source library. Last resort would be to convert this logic to old-school `for` loops with great caution to avoid common bugs:

```
void in_place_reorder(std::span<std::byte> buffer){ 
    if (std::endian::native == std::endian::big)
        for(std::size_t i = 0; (i + 3) < size(buffer); i += 3)
            std::swap(buffer[i],buffer[i+2]);
};

std::vector<std::byte> in_vec{/*...*/};
auto out_vec = in_vec;
in_place_reorder(out_vec);
```

The alternative that keeps source intact would be difficult to read and error-prone. Possible to write, but with extra caution and lots of tweaks. It would be a bit faster than above sample, but trickier. I will skip that part because of my obsession for good design that complicates things.

Comment: Nice, btw didn't quite understsand why the test for big endian - I think you meant if (std::endian::native == std::endian::little).  Also +1 for the ranges implementation, not sure about performance with ranges as I'm reasonably new to the more advanced ranges apis

Comment: I have a bug. Let me fix it.

Comment: If you are working on a machine with native little endian, then it's rational to keep the order. You can skip that part if it doesn't fit. I had a bug in first snippet: `stride` was missing. It means every other nth element.

Comment: thanks for looking into the bug - unfortunately I am having compiling on latest Windows vs2022 preview with std++latest - I have #included both <ranges> & <range/v3/all.hpp> ... error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::tuple<_Ty &,_Ty &,_Ty &>' to 'std::tuple<_Ty &,_Ty &,_Ty &> &' - looks like I have to change for (auto& [first, _, last]... to for (auto [first, _, last] (removing the ref capture).

Comment: `auto&&` should work. There are still subtleties in structured binding that bite hard. I normally don't use universal references, but sometimes it seems the better way.

Comment: You can just `chunk(3)` instead of `adjacent | stride`, then `swap(chk.back(), chk.front()` or `ranges::reverse(chk)`. Either one that runs fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the problem is only inverting the byte order in a sequence of three byte ints: no processor today has any support for three byte ints, so you'll have to manipulate the individual bytes. Something like

```
unsigned char* src;
unsigned char* dest;
for ( int i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++ i ) {
    dest[0] = src[2];
    dest[1] = src[1];
    dest[2] = src[0];
    src += 3;
    dest += 3;
}
```

With `src` and `dest` appropriately initialized, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I found that gcc with -O3 and -mssse3 or better does a decent job vectorizing the simple version by James. If you need more performance and you are willing to add a platform-specific version, here is one that uses SSSE3 (and therefore should work well on any modern platform with AVX or better). In my tests it's about 2-3 times faster than the compiler version.

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstddef>
// using std::ptrdiff_t
#include <cstdint>
// using std::uint8_t

void as_ssse3(std::uint8_t* out, const std::uint8_t* in, std::ptrdiff_t samples)
{
    const __m128i shuffle = _mm_setr_epi8(
          /* sample 1 */ 2, 1, 0, /* sample 2 */ 5, 4, 3,
          /* sample 3 */ 8, 7, 6, /* sample 4 */ 11, 10, 9,
          /* sample 5 */ 14, 13, 12, /* tail */ 15);
    std::ptrdiff_t i;
    /*
     * Process 15 bytes per iteration with a 16 byte vector.
     * Be careful not to read past the end of the array. The
     * last sample always needs to be processed separately
     */
    for(i = 0; i + 5 < samples; i += 5) {
        __m128i cur = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) (in + i * 3));
        cur = _mm_shuffle_epi8(cur, shuffle);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*) (out + i * 3), cur);
    }
    /*
     * Simple loop for last few entries.
     * We load first, store then. This allows in-place transformations
     */
    for(; i < samples; ++i) {
        auto t1 = in[i * 3 + 2], t2 = in[i * 3 + 1], t3 = in[i * 3];
        out[i * 3] = t1;
        out[i * 3 + 1] = t2;
        out[i * 3 + 2] = t3;
    }
}
```

I don't think larger AVX2 or AVX512 vectors are worth it. The trouble is that then you have to shuffle across lanes and that tends to be slower but I haven't attempted it yet.

There is a neat little micro-optimization in that scalar loop for the last few entries: By loading all values first and storing them afterwards, we can operate in-place, although I wouldn't recommend it due to the store-load forwarding in the vector loop. A side-effect is that GCC will merge two of the byte-sized write operations into one 2-byte write.

If you *do* want fast in-place operation, here is a slightly more messy SSE-4.1 version. My tests show similar speed to the version above in out-of-place operation despite the higher instruction count and much better performance if `in == out`.

```cpp
void as_sse41(std::uint8_t* out, const std::uint8_t* in, std::ptrdiff_t samples)
{
    const __m128i shuffle1 = _mm_setr_epi8(
          /* sample 1 */ 2, 1, 0, /* sample 2 */ 5, 4, 3,
          /* sample 3 */ 8, 7, 6, /* sample 4 */ 11, 10, 9,
          /* sample 5 */ 14, 13, 12, /* sample 6 */ -1);
    const __m128i shuffle2 = _mm_setr_epi8(
          /* sample 6 */ 0, -1, /* sample 7 */ 4, 3, 2,
          /* sample 8 */ 7, 6, 5, /* sample 9 */ 10, 9, 8,
          /* sample 10 */ 13, 12, 11, /* sample 11 */ -1, 15);
    const __m128i shuffle3 = _mm_setr_epi8(
          /* sample 11 */ -1, /* sample 12 */ 3, 2, 1,
          /* sample 13 */ 6, 5, 4, /* sample 14 */ 9, 8, 7,
          /* sample 15 */ 12, 11, 10, /* sample 16 */ 15, 14, 13);
    std::ptrdiff_t i;
    for(i = 0; i + 16 <= samples; i += 16) {
        __m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) (in + i * 3));
        __m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) (in + i * 3 + 16));
        __m128i v3 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) (in + i * 3 + 32));
        v1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v1, shuffle1);
        v1 = _mm_insert_epi8(v1, in[i * 3 + 17], 15);
        v2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v2, shuffle2);
        v2 = _mm_insert_epi8(v2, in[i * 3 + 15], 1);
        v2 = _mm_insert_epi8(v2, in[i * 3 + 32], 14);
        v3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v3, shuffle3);
        v3 = _mm_insert_epi8(v3, in[i * 3 + 30], 0);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*) (out + i * 3), v1);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*) (out + i * 3 + 16), v2);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*) (out + i * 3 + 32), v3);
    }
    for(; i < samples; ++i) {
        auto t1 = in[i * 3 + 2], t2 = in[i * 3 + 1], t3 = in[i * 3];
        out[i * 3] = t1;
        out[i * 3 + 1] = t2;
        out[i * 3 + 2] = t3;
    }
}
```